# How to play .pls in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Android Media Player:
I'm able to play .mp3 file from URL.
While playing .pls getting eroor.

Code:

```
try{
String url=".pls url";
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
}catch(Exception 
System.out.println("@@ Exception while playing: "+e);
mediaPlayer .release();
mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Error:

```
09-12 12:44:04.026: E/MediaPlayer(704): error (1, -2147483648)
09-12 12:44:04.026: I/System.out(704): @@ Exception while playing: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Answer (score 1):

If by `pls` you mean playlist information file, then mediaplayer cannot handle `pls` files.

.pls files are not media files. So you cannot play .pls files. Usually .pls are handled by the  app and app extracts the information from the pls file and play the music file to which pls is pointing to.

Comment: Opened (extracted) .pls in textpad and found IP address (File1=value). How to play audio using IP address which points to .pls file. Want to play .pls from URL.

Comment: i have never tried it, but i guess you can directly set the source with the url using setdatsource

Comment: When I tried to play IPAddress.songs.pls getting mentioned error. But am able to play .mp3 from the same site.

Comment: as i said you cannot give  pls fileformat url to mediaplayer. you have to parse pls format and then extract mp3 urls from this file and then pass it to mediaplayer

Comment: I'm not finding anything like .mp3 in received .pls file. .pls has Ip.

Comment: How to get .mp3 files from .pls please provide the solution am also struck that.

Answer (score 0):

```
String musicUlrPath;
LinkedList<String> streamingUrlList;

        streamingUrlList=new LinkedList<String>();

    ExecuteArrayList executeArrayList=new ExecuteArrayList();
                    executeArrayList.execute("blank");



class ExecuteArrayList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>

        {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                streamingUrlList=getStreamingUrl(pathFromJson);//you are geting path during json response 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                       }
                return null;

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                musicUlrPath=(streamingUrlList.get(0));


            }

        }



    public LinkedList<String> getStreamingUrl(String url) {

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "get streaming url");
        final BufferedReader br;
        String murl = null;
        LinkedList<String> murls = null;
        try {
            URLConnection mUrl = new URL(url).openConnection();
            br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(mUrl.getInputStream()));
            murls = new LinkedList<String>();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String line = br.readLine();

                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    murl = parseLine(line);
                    if (murl != null && !murl.equals("")) {
                        murls.add(murl);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "url to stream :" + murl);
        return murls;
    }

    private String parseLine(String line) {
        if (line == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String trimmed = line.trim();
        if (trimmed.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
            return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("http"));
        }
        return "";
    }
```

now set the extracted path

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicUlrPath);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Extract pls file in notepad , It will show like this
playlist]
File1=Alternative\everclear -URL
Title1=Everclear - So Much For The Afterglow
Length1=233    
File2=Comedy\Weird Al - Everything You Know Is Wrong.mp3   
.
.   
NumberOfEntries=5    
Version=2.

Use that URL in Media player.It will work.
```